# Weird behavior when using pattern matching with mixins

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, mixins

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't make this work.

Suppose we have the following code:

```
object T {
  def method: Unit = {
    trait Mixin
    case class Foo(foo: String)

    val f = new Foo("hi") with Mixin
    f match {
      case Foo(s) => println(s)
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles and prints "hi" when I call Test.method. The pattern match code can even be inside nested methods or nested functions, and it works. However, if I move the case class outside of method and directly attached to T2:

```
object T2 {

  case class Foo(foo: String)

  def method: Unit = {
    trait Mixin

    val f = new Foo("hi") with Mixin
    f match {
      case Foo(s) => println(s)
    }
  }
}
```

it throws the following error:

```
Error:(183, 12) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : T2.Foo
 required: T2.Foo with Mixin
      case Foo(s) => println(s)
           ^
```

If now I don't use Mixin, and only make val f = new Foo("hi"), it works fine again. It also works if I try to match on its type:

```
val f = new Foo("hi") with Mixin
f match {
  case f: Foo => println("I am a Foo")
}
```

Why doesn't T2 work, if the case class (and all of its generated methods) are in scope, and why would it matter where it is defined? In my real code, I have several case classes, in several modules, and the pattern matchers are all over the place, so I can't just move everything inside the same method, and I'd prefer if I don't have to get rid of the mixins, so what other alternative do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are a few things going on.

- The Scala compiler is trying to figure out what types you are matching on.
- You've mixed a top level type with a local type, which seems to confuse the compiler.

In `T`, both `Foo` and `Mixin` are declared locally in the scope of your method. A local type isn't necessary available outside of its scope (in this case, `method`). Because everything is in the same scope, it's easy for the compiler to figure out what you're trying to do.

In `T2`, `Foo` is declared at the top level but `Mixin` is still a local type. This seems to throw off the compiler. You can help the compiler by specifically typeing value `f` to `Foo`, which will allow your snippet to compile.

```
object T2 {
  case class Foo(foo: String)
  def method: Unit = {
    trait Mixin
    val f: Foo = new Foo("hi") with Mixin
    f match {
      case Foo(s) => println(s)
    }
  }
}
```

I wish I could give a more detailed (and guaranteed accurate) explanation.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I can move trait Mixin around all I want, and the compiler never complains, it's only when I move the case class. If the case class is inside method, and the mixin is outside, it compiles fine. Also, thanks for the solution. It'll be a bit uncomfortable casting everywhere, but at least it will work.